# How to open browser and youtube app with the title as URL in android with intent create chooser

Tags: android, android-intent, audio-player, android-music-player

[image]I am making an android music player application in which i want to add an search functionality that's why i need to implement this like:

I want to search the song name and create the chooser for youtube and all installed browser with the song title and not for the url

I think i am unable to describe my question so please see the below may be it will help you to understand:-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://stackoverflow.com/"));
//here i want to set like that intent.setData("my song title")
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"search"));
```

but if i am doing this it show me -NO APPS CAN PERFORM THIS ACTION

so idon't know how to put the title as url in intent

please remember this user also able to search this on youtube

Answer (score 2):

You can start two separate searches with your query as follows:

**Youtube Search**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
intent.setPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, "Sunday Bloody Sunday");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Browser Search**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, "Sunday Bloody Sunday");
startActivity(intent);
```

Note that if the song is well known, one of the first results of the browser search will be the Youtube video.

**Edit**

Here is auto to create a search query for both Youtube and browsers:

```
private void startSearchIntent(String query) {
    List<Intent> browserIntents = new ArrayList<>();
    // Find browser intents
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH), 0);

    // Create a search intent for each browser that was found
    for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
        browserIntent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, query);
        browserIntent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase());
        browserIntents.add(browserIntent);
    }

    // Create Youtube Intent
    Intent youtubeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
    youtubeIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
    youtubeIntent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, query);
    youtubeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(youtubeIntent, query);
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, browserIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
    startActivity(chooserIntent);

}
```

Then you just have to call the method:

```
startSearchIntent("Sunday Bloody Sunday");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes buddy it helped me so much but not satisfied my question please see the image above it shows multiple different types of application for search

Comment: See my edited answer, I added what you are looking for.